# Converting Matrix to Graph using Jung

Tags: java, jung

Can anyone show me how to use JUNG to convert a matrix to a graph? I am still fairly new to JUNG and i can't find anything useful

Comment: Could you provide example code of what you've tried, and how exactly it hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0):

```
Graph<MyNode, MyEdge> graph = new DirectedSparseGraph<>();

for (i = 0; i < num_nodes; i++) {
  // you can skip this if you have no isolated nodes in your graph
  graph.addNode(new MyNode(i));
  for (j = 0; j < num_nodes; j++) {
    if (matrix[i][j] != 0) {
      graph.addEdge(new MyEdge(), new MyNode(i), new MyNode(j));
    }
  }
}
```

That's the basic idea.  The details will differ depending on what vertex/edge objects you want, whether you have a directed or an undirected graph, what the entries of your matrix look like, etc.